# DiagrammeR - add number formatting and sublabels to node

Tags: r, graphviz, diagrammer

I wish to add labels to my nodes, a main label with font size X and a sublabel with font size X * 0.5. My sublabel needs to have number formatting where 87650 is displayed as 87,650.

Is this possible in DiagrammeR?

My numerical sublabel data comes from a data frame.

```
library(DiagrammeR)
grViz("
  digraph test {
    graph []

    node [shape = box]
    A [label = '@@1']
    B [label = 'BarFoo']

    A -> B
  }
  [1]: paste0('Main Heading \\n', sum(iris$Sepal.Length)*100)
")
```

Comment: using html is probably the easiest way. But is is a pita trying to balance the quotations with Diagrammer when adding the string inline. Would this suit as an alt : `var =paste0("<<FONT POINT-SIZE='60'> Main Heading </FONT><BR/>", paste0("<FONT POINT-SIZE='10'>", format(sum(iris$Sepal.Length)*100, big.mark=","), '</FONT>>'))` and then use `[1]: var` in the `grViz` call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use ***format()*** to process the number first, and then call the result later.

Please run the example code below:

```
library(DiagrammeR)

mysum <- sum(iris$Sepal.Length)*100

input <- format(mysum, big.mark = ",")



grViz("  
  digraph test {  
    graph []  

    node [shape = box]  
    A [label = '@@1']  
    B [label = 'BarFoo']  

    A -> B  
  }  
  [1]: paste0('Main Heading \\n', input) 
")
```

[You should be able to see a similar outcome like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Iumc.png)